# Proper way for Javascript to read MySQL data through Java

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, json

I am now learning while developing my Java web app using JSF, and I was asked to study on using Javascript to create datatable/report dynamically and present it via .html/.xhtml. I am required to use [Datatables.net](https://www.datatables.net/examples/index) to produce the table. The backend process is using Java instead of Php. Since it is so rare to use this method, I got no idea on this. My thought so far is:

**MySQL data**  --convert to (processed by Java code)-->   **Json** --read by-> **Javascript**

How do I process the SQL data? Can I directly run the query inside Java like:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT("[",
     GROUP_CONCAT(
          CONCAT("{name:'",NAME,"'"),
          CONCAT("email:'",email,"'"),
          CONCAT(",address:'",address,"'}")
     )
,"]") AS JSON FROM customer
```

If so, how do I parse the data out and make sure Javascript will read it?

The another way I found is to use some library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or something similar.

Explanations or examples about this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: This is far too broad. I would create a REST interface using JAX-RS / Jersey. But again.. far too broad.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Maybe the direction I study was wrong haha....